# Using blender model in A-Frame

Tags: blender, aframe, virtual-reality

The model I created in blender seems to be glitching/clipping when adding it to A-frame.

I created a model in Blender, and noticed the model seemed to be glitching. Changing the View clip start and end resolved the issue on Blender. Now, adding the same model to A-frame the same seems to be happening. According to A-frame's documentation, the clipping cannot be changed for 3D models. Is there a better solution for this, either for A-frame or maybe for the model itself in Blender?

Here is a [glitch](https:///https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe) of the model, as well as the code used:
https://evening-abounding-mochi.glitch.me/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
       <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="model" src="https://cdn.glitch.me/65c0d096-2f01-45b9-b6ad-eab94f968ba2/sondagem4.glb?v=1682021067857"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity gltf-model="#model" position="0 -500 -3000" rotation="0 225 0" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

The model itself is in my github:
https://github.com/martacorreia29/MonteDosCastelinhosWebAR/blob/main/app/src/resources/sondagem4%20-%20noMontain.glb

Here is the model in both softwares:
[model in A-frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XCp7.png)
[model in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMzlV.png)

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this and ask, instead, on the blender stack exchange site

Comment: in what format did you export it?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski In glb

Comment: @Rob A-frame is a framewrok for web xr, I'm not sure whether the issue is with the model itself or the way I'm passing it to A-frame. Blender stack exchange only deals with model issues

Comment: did you try your model with don mccurdys [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)? It'll provide some info whether its related to the export, or is it something in aframe

Comment: @MartaCorreia there is also an [aframe slack](https://aframevr.slack.com/join/shared_invite/zt-f6rne3ly-ekVaBU~Xu~fsZHXr56jacQ) :)

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski In the gltf-viewer is rendering fine, so it should really be an issue with A-frame. I will look into the a-frame slack, thank you so much! :)

Comment: just to be clear - Don's `gltf-viewer` is created in threejs, which `aframe` is based on (and is usually a bit behind to be stable) - best case scenario the scene / renderer / camera need some tweaking. It'll be hard to find out the cause without the model. If you can create a [glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe) it would be helpful

Comment: If this is a programming question then you are required to post a [mcve] I don't see how this is a programming question and, therefore, off topic on SO.

Comment: I have updated the question, with a link to my model on github, as well as glitch where the clipping is visible as well. Thank you :)

Comment: I think its the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056314/my-a-frame-spheres-have-jagged-edges-when-viewed-from-a-distance-why) - the model is huge and far away, so the renderer has issues with determining the distances properly with a linear depth buffer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been trying to go from your suggestion, but I'm still having issues. The logarithmicDepthBuffer does fix it on the glitch code, and I'm able to see everything perfectly https://ancient-grand-food.glitch.me/ , but on my local web app it still glitches a lot. I am using React, so I'm searching on possible issues on using A-frame with React and the rendering of the models.

Comment: Problem solved, I just really had to rescale the module significantly, though it still needs the renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true" in the a-scene component to be able to work 100%. Thank you Piotr!

Answer (score 0):

I rescaled the model down significantly in Blender. I also added the logarithmicDepthBuffer parameter to the a-scene component, like it was suggested by Piotr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056314/my-a-frame-spheres-have-jagged-edges-when-viewed-from-a-distance-why).

```
<a-scene renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true"> </a-scene>
```